# Adding p2p-rpl patch to instant contiki

Tags: c, contiki

I'm trying to apply the p2p-rpl patch offered by http://contiki-p2p-rpl.gforge.inria.fr/  to contiki, but I'm facing the following errors while trying to make the patch:

```
../../../core/dev/sht11.c: In function ‘sstart’:
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:74:3: error: ‘P1DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:74:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:74:12: error: ‘P1OUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c: In function ‘sreset’:
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:93:3: error: ‘P1DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:94:3: error: ‘P1OUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c: In function ‘swrite’:
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:116:7: error: ‘P1DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:120:5: error: ‘P1OUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:129:10: error: ‘P1IN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c: In function ‘sread’:
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:142:3: error: ‘P1DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:145:5: error: ‘P1OUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:147:8: error: ‘P1IN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c: In function ‘sht11_init’:
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:215:3: error: ‘P1OUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:217:3: error: ‘P1DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c: In function ‘sht11_off’:
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:230:3: error: ‘P1OUT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:232:3: error: ‘P1DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../../../core/dev/sht11.c: In function ‘scmd’:
../../../core/dev/sht11.c:256:9: error: ‘P1IN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [obj_sky/sht11.o] Error 1
```